# Unable to access document under the collection

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

In this case, I  try to  build up a app. So two types of users can be accessed through this app. then what I want to do is, document from a collection in firestore  want to add to recyclerview in fragment. In this app, user was registered and he can request leave and I want to code, if user send a leave request then he can see his  request from a recycleview and not others' leave requests. but it not work for me.
So if you got any answer to this problem , please help me.
This is my code details
java file

```
public class status extends Fragment {

 View v;
    RecyclerView statusRecycleView;
   // ArrayList<Model> listModel;
    //RecyclerViewAdapterSt recyclerViewAdapterSt;
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser FUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    String UserId = FUser.getUid();
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false);
        statusRecycleView = v.findViewById(R.id.status_recyclerview);
        //listModel = new ArrayList<>();
       // recyclerViewAdapterSt = new RecyclerViewAdapterSt(listModel);
       // statusRecycleView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterSt);
        statusRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("ApplyLeave").document(UserId).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

            }
        };
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Model> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Model, status.myViewHolder>(options) {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public status.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_status,parent,false);
                    return new status.myViewHolder(v);
                }
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull status.myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model model) {
                    holder.h_reason.setText(model.getU_reason());
                    holder.h_name.setText(model.getU_nameL());
                    holder.h_selectLeave.setText(model.getU_select_leave());
                    holder.h_leaveType.setText(model.getU_leave_type());
                    holder.h_fromDate.setText(model.getU_from_date());
                    holder.h_toDate.setText(model.getU_to_date());
                }
            };
            statusRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            statusRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            statusRecycleView.setAdapter(adapter);



       /* db.collection("users").document(UserId).collection("Apply Leave").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                     for(DocumentSnapshot d:list){
                          Model model = d.toObject(Model.class);
                         listModel.add(model);
                     }
                     recyclerViewAdapterSt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
             }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure:" + e.toString());
            }
        });*/

            return  v ;
        }

        public static class myViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView h_reason;
            TextView h_name;
            TextView h_selectLeave;
            TextView h_leaveType;
            TextView h_fromDate;
            TextView h_toDate;
            public myViewHolder( View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
            h_reason = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_reason_status);
            h_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_status);
            h_selectLeave = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_selectLeave_status);
            h_leaveType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_leaveType_status);
            h_fromDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fromDate_status);
            h_toDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_toDate_status);
        }
        }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }


    }
```

this is fragment_status.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".status">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_status"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:id="@+id/status_recyclerview">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

So what I want to know, how to user can only see their leavue request not others?
this is place where I stucked... from this, all the request were shown to the user. I want to code to show only the user's requests to user.

```
        Query query_two = db.collection("applyLeave");
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Model_two> options_two = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model_two>()
                .setQuery(query_two, Model_two.class)
                .build();

        adapter_two = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Model_two, tmyViewHolder>(options_two) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public tmyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_status_admin, parent, false);
                return new tmyViewHolder(v);
            }
```

this is my firestore details....

[image]

[image]

so you can see same id was highlighted there. so what I need is, if user log to the app, then only his leave requests have to be shown in recycleview. Can you help me??

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No , I dont have any errors also. but the expected one is , when the user request a leave, then the details of that request has to be shown in the recycleview in another fragment.

Comment: but in this case, no details was shown. the very special case, if not only you, but also other users can log into the app and request leaves. but only you can see your request details.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Simple Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries). For example, to only get application of username nirmal78,

```
Query query_two = db.collection("applyLeave").whereEqualTo("u_nameL", "nirmal78");
```

Make sure you have at least one field that is unique to each user.

Comment: thanks for your commit, but the case is, this code was applicable for any user who log into the app. so this is not only for the nirmal78. so that is the case.... so do you have any idea?

Comment: Well, that depends on how you store and identify users. Ideally, you would have a uid, or username unique to each user, so whenever a user logs in, you would use their id/name to get their leave.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have named the `applyLeave` document for the user after their UID. In that case you can query on the document ID with:

```
Query query_two = db.collection("applyLeave")
   .whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), UserId)
```

Since document IDs are unique within a collection, this will match at most one document, which will then be shown in your view.

---

In general, you'll likely have multiple `applyLeave` documents for the same user, and will store the UID of the user **inside** the document, rather than as the document ID. In that case, you can query on the field **name** with:

```
Query query_two = db.collection("applyLeave")
   .whereEqualTo("uid", UserId)
```

Where `"uid"` is the name of the field where you store the UID.

Comment: thank you for your commit & you mean "uid" means the given id for the user that was under field name "u_company_id"? am I right and UserId means  autogenaarte id for current user or something??

Comment: A UID is the ID of a user in Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...It worked,

```
db.collection("users").document(UserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                        usernameM = task.getResult().getString("u_name");
                        Log.d("..............", usernameM);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Query query = db.collection("applyLeave").whereEqualTo("u_nameL",usernameM);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Model> options= new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                .setQuery(query, Model.class)
                .build();
```